# How to align with the text by jQuery?

Tags: jquery, alignment

How to calculate how much px from the left is the text?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You mean, how to measure the padding/margin via jQuery? It so, you can do this:

```
paddingleft = parseInt($('#yourElement').css("padding-left"));
marginleft  = parseInt($('#yourElement').css("margin-left"));
```